# Iterating through a dataframe when plotting an histogram

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib, histogram

I am having trouble in a probably very simple task.

I've got a dataframe containing the results of several n models:

| actuals | model1 | model2 | model3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.12 | 0.21 | 0.54 | 0.81 |
| 0.41 | 0.52 | 0.41 | 0.21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to generate *one* plot containing the histograms of the several n models without having to call each time `plt.hist(df["actuals"], name="actuals", color="blue")` for each row independently. I tried some for-loop constructions but I haven't figured it out until now... Plus I havent found any suitable method for plotting directly the column name in the legend and for the histograms to change colors without setting it manually.

Hopefully someone can help me! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your aim is to plot the distribution of values per each column of the table on the same histogram:

```
data = {
        'Model_A':np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.5, size=(100,)),
        'Model_B':np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=1, size=(100,)),
        'Model_C':np.random.uniform(low=0.3, high=0.6, size=(100,)),
        'Model_D':np.random.uniform(low=0.1, high=0.7, size=(100,)),
        'Model_E':np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(100,))
       } 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df.plot.hist(bins=12, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, haven't thought it would be that simple, thank you! Is there also a way to avoid using the same colors multiple times? The colors repeat after the first 6 columns.